# ASUS 1005PE runs hotter and drains the battery quicker since installing 14.04

Tags: 14.04, asus, battery, jupiter

Since migrating to 14.04, my ASUS Eee PC 1005PE laptop runs very hot and the battery seems to drain faster.  I believe it may be attributable to the loss of the Jupiter application that replicated the ASUS-created application available when running Windows.

I am aware the Jupiter code is no longer supported/available on 14.04, are there other applications available that could provide the same or similar feature set as Jupiter?

Thank you in advance for your thoughtful response and assistance.